# ActionBarSherlock Sample Demos code not compiling

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I can't compile the ActionBarSherlock Sample Demos code

I have imported the SampleList Project  in to ADT (Build: v21.1.0-569685)

But I get lots of basic errors

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type  TabNavigation.java  /SampleList/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos  line 24 Java Problem
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a variable  FeatureToggles.java /SampleList/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos  line 141    Java Problem
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a variable  FeatureToggles.java /SampleList/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos  line 147    Java Problem
```

And also an error to the library location, I'm not sure why this is?

When I go to Properties -> Android -> the Library actionbarsherlock has a cross by it

Comment: try following their video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUGn-zu3uhk

Comment: Thanks for the comment Udi, the project structure has changed since this video was done making it harder to follow. I'll try and work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to my own question really needed to ensure that

1.) the Library Actionbarsherlock has been created in the workspace and delete a duplicate android-support-v4.jar in that project

2.) Delete the original reference to the library Actionbarsherlock, in the samples project and re-add

3.) Then add android-support-v4.jar to a new libs folder

**Detailed steps for this are:**

Import ‘JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.3.1-0/Actionbarsherlock’ as an android project

Delete the Android Dependencies ‘android-support-v4.jar’ in the actionbarsherlock project.  As this there is already a reference to this in samples project. Clean all projects

In the project wanting to use Actionbarsherlock in this case the sample ‘actionbarsherlock-samples’ Go to Project Properties -> Android -> remove any broken references to the ‘actionbarsherlock’ library , then add the library project
The library project ‘Actionbarsherlock ‘ still has errors in it then

So, what I did to fix it, was:

1. Right click on your project ("actionbarsherlock") in the navigation menu on the left.
2. Click 'Properties'.
3. Click 'Java Build Path' on the left hand navigation pane.
4. Click 'Add External Jars' button on the right.
5. Navigate to: "\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4"
6. Choose "android-support-v4.jar", then click 'Open', then click 'Ok'.
7. Left Click on your Project ("actionbarsherlock")
8. Click 'Project' at the top, then click 'Clean', then click 'Ok'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Actionbarsherlock to your project.

Right Click your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path
Find the Android Tab

In the Library section > Add
Double Click on actionbarsherlock and click Apply.

Comment: Double clicking on ..\..\actionbarsherlock in the Library section does nothing it just has a red 'X' next to it. I've tried importing the 'actionbarsherlock' folder into the workspace as a library, when I do if I click the 'Add...' button I can see the project it has a green tick next to it. But when I close the window and go back to it , it has a red 'x' again

Comment: Remove the one with the red cross. Then re add the new one.

Comment: I remove the orginal then add the reference to D:\Projects\Eclipse Projects\actionbarsherlock it looks fine and has a green arrow next to it. But when I close the window and re-open it it turns back to red

Comment: Probably because something went wrong when importing. Delete all files. Close Eclipse , restart. The retry importing.

Comment: Ok deleted everything. Set up a new weorkspace. On import of Demo's it says 'Resource '/SampleList' already exists. Not sure why has the workspace is empty of projects. The same behaviour is seen when trying to add the library actionbarsherlock

Comment: Sorted this now, I will post the answer soon As I don't have any rep need to wait 10 hours before giving the answer